# How make only show user location marker only not rest of the markers in Google place picker?

Tags: android, google-places-api

How to make only show user location marker only not rest of the markers in Google place picker now it is showing a lot of location marker and our customer confused which is whom

Comment: when you only want current location, why are you using place picker in first place ?

Comment: it contain search and it is showing user current position faster that other soluctions

Comment: that is why i am using this

Comment: is there any paramater to change user marker color

Comment: add it is difficult to move marker if i use map

Comment: Place picker is not customizable like that as far as I know

Comment: You can add certain filters to restrict the search results though

Comment: we juest need to alow user to set location and we need there lan and lon can you please suggest better way

Comment: Just give a button saying `Get Current Location` and fetch the location using gps or network provider